# Customising Json.NET serialisation based on compile time type

Tags: c#, json.net

Consider the following `Json.NET` serialization style code:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
class A {
  ...
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
class B : A {
  ...
}

class MyConverter {
  public override void WriteJson(
    JsonWriter writer, 
    object value, 
    JsonSerializer serializer) { ... }
}

class CA {
  public readonly A _x;
  CA(A x) { _x = x; }
}

class CB {
  public readonly B _x;
  CB(B x) { _x = x; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args) {
  B b = new B(...);
  CA ca = new CA(b);
  CB cb = new CB(b);
 
  string caStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ca);
  string cbStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cb);
}
```

In the code above, both `CA` and `CB` are serialised to the exact same string `caStr` and `cbStr`. But I want `MyConverter` to know about the compile time type and act differently. In the case of `CB`, the contained `B _x` should just be serialised in the default manner. By in the case of `CA`, `MyConverter` should tag what it serialises in some defined way and then serilise the contained `A _x` (which has a runtime type of `B`) in the usual default way B is serialised.

So, my question is, can a custom `JsonConverter` receive information on the compile time type of the type it is serialising? In this case adjusting the serialising call won't do, as I need this to work with member objects also, of which I'm not directly calling to serialise.

Note that whilst what I'm actually doing is *similar* to `TypeNameHandling` it's not exactly the same and I need to conform to an external spec so I really need the custom behaviour here.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that can be compiled, linked and run, and includes the JSON you want to generate for your classes `A` and `B`?  In comments you wrote *As noted in the question, I need to conform to a spec as the data is read by other applications* but you don't tell is what that spec is, so we're having to guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that converters applied to properties take precedence over other converters to use a customized converter instance for `A _x`.

As explained in its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#JsonConverter):

> JsonConverters can be defined and specified in a number of places: in an attribute on a member, in an attribute on a class, and added to the JsonSerializer's converters collection. **The priority of which JsonConverter is used is the JsonConverter defined by attribute on a member, then the JsonConverter defined by an attribute on a class, and finally any converters passed to the JsonSerializer.**

This makes it possible to pass the declared type information (or any other compile-time information) to `MyConverter` when applied to `A _x` by using [converter parameters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm).  In comments you wrote *I need the compile time type revealed to the custom converter* so if by *compile time type* you meant the ***declared type `A` of `_x`*** you may do that as follows.

Modify `MyConverter` to add a constructor with a `declaredType` parameter:

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter 
{
    public MyConverter() : this(typeof(A)) { }

    public MyConverter(Type declaredType) => this.DeclaredType = declaredType;

    public Type DeclaredType { get; init; }

    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer,  object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        // This is just a mockup, your question doesn't specify your requirements.
        var a = (A)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        if (DeclaredType == typeof(A) && a is B b)
        {
            //By in the case of CA, MyConverter should tag what it serialises in some defined way
            writer.WritePropertyName("isB");
            writer.WriteValue(true);
        }
        // Add whatever logic you need to serialize A
        // Add whatever additional logic you need to serialize B
        // And end the object
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then modify your classes as follows:

```
class CA {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter), typeof(A))]
    public readonly A _x;
    public CA(A _x) { this._x = _x; } // The constructor argument names must have the same case-invariant name as the corresponding member for the converter to be applied
}

class CB { 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter), typeof(B))]
    public readonly B _x;
    public CB(B _x) { this._x = _x; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
class A {
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter), typeof(B))]
class B : A {
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could make `MyConverter` [generic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) in the declared type:

```
class MyConverter<TDeclared> : JsonConverter<TDeclared> where TDeclared : A
{
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer,  TDeclared value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        // This is just a mockup, your question doesn't specify your requirements.
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        if (typeof(TDeclared) != value.GetType())
        {
            //By in the case of CA, MyConverter should tag what it serialises in some defined way
            writer.WritePropertyName("isB");
            writer.WriteValue(value.GetType() == typeof(B));
        }
        // Add whatever logic you need to serialize A
        // Add whatever additional logic you need to serialize B
        // And end the object
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    public override TDeclared ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TDeclared existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And apply it as follows:

```
class CA {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<A>))]
    public readonly A _x;
    public CA(A _x) { this._x = _x; } // The constructor argument names must have the same case-invariant name as the corresponding member for the converter to be applied
}

class CB { 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<B>))]
    public readonly B _x;
    public CB(B _x) { this._x = _x; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<A>))]
class A {
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<B>))]
class B : A {
}
```

Either way, `CA ca` will be serialized as follows:

```json
{"_x":{"isB":true}}
```

While `CB cb` will still get serialized like so:

```json
{"_x":{}}
```

Notes:

- As Json.NET is a contract-based serializer, it generally doesn't provide information about the current serialization stack when serializing an object.  The parent object decides what to serialize, the child object decides how to serialize itself.  Thus e.g. `MyConverter` isn't informed whether the container object is of type `CA` or `CB` or what specific property of that container is being written.

  Custom member converters are the one notable exception to that general principle.
- In both cases my code assumes that you do not want `B` tagged when serialized standalone.  If you do want it tagged standalone please edit your question to clarify.
- When deserializing an immutable type with a parameterized constructor, Json.NET matches argument names to properties using a case-invariant match in order to use find and use `[JsonProperty]` or `[JsonConverter]` attributes that may be applied to the property.  Thus I modified your constructor argument names to `_x` to ensure `MyConverter` is applied during deserialization.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/307ais) for the parameterized converter, and #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7ebWO) for the generic version.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET has a [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) config parameter to control this behavior.

```
class CA 
{
    A _x;
    CA(A x) { _x = x; }

    // Added this just so we can confirm the solution easily
    public A X => _x;
}

B b = new B(...);
CA ca = new CA(b);

string ca_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ca, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});

var ca_deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CA>(ca_json);

Console.WriteLine(ca_deserialized.X is B); // true
```

When activated, Json.NET will add a hidden "$type" field to the JSON, which tells the deserializer exactly which type to use. If you inspect the JSON, you'll see something along the lines of:

```
"$type": "MyNamespace.CA",
```

Comment: As noted in the question, I need to conform to a spec as the data is read by other applications, so this doesn't help. I need the compile time type revealed to the custom converter

Comment: So `TypeNameHandling`, at least in the form above, doesn't help, as the question mentions.

Comment: @Clinton: What you're asking for, from a language perspective, isn't quite clear. You want the type to be decided by the _code_, not the JSON data (as per your comment). But your code specifically states that `CA._x` is of type `A`, but you want to use type `B`. Let's make a `new CA(new A())` and `new CA(new B())`. Post serialization, they have to look the same (as per your comment of needing to conform to a spec). So when they get deserialized, precisely how is the code meant to be able to choose to use a different type for `_x` for these two structurally identical JSON strings?

Comment: @Clinton: The core question is: not _all_ `CA` objects have an `_x` of type `B`. Therefore, someone has to make a choice between using type `A` or type `B` in the deserialization process. Who is making that decision, and based on what information are they able to make that decision, and where is that information to be found/derived? (Note that "who" means classes, external services _or_ people, not just people)

Comment: When Json.NET reflects through `CA` and `CB` (as it needs to do to serialise them), itcan know the compile time types. Just like on deserialisation, one needs to use the reflection to determine the compile time types so one knows what to serialisation to call. The issue is that whilst the `ReadJson` has a parameter of type `Type`, that indicates the compile time type, `WriteJson` does not. If it did I wouldn't have this issue. Json.NET I imagine has this information (indeed it needs it when `TypeNameHandling` is on, but I just don't know how to access it in the `WriteJson` case.

Comment: @Clinton: Default class serialization happens class agnostically. The serializer uses reflection to say "object, give me your properties and their values". However, that is not how deserialization works, because deserialization **needs** to know the type of the object it needs to initialize. Serialization causes no instantiation, but deserialization does, and instantiation bring with it certain requirements such as needing to know the type to instantiate. **Someone** has to tell the deserializer which type to use. Either the information is contained in the JSON, or it's chosen from the code.

Comment: @Clinton: In other words, `WriteJson` doesn't need to know the class of the payload you're already passing into it. The payload itself is information enough. However, in `ReadJson`, there is no payload object (yet), the method has to instantiate one. In that case, the method needs to know what type that is.