# Is there a way to access customParameters object[] from within a custom JsonConverter class implementation?

Tags: .net-core, json.net, model-binding, custom-attributes, jsonconvert

I wrote a custom JsonConverter called `CompententsConverter` and it works fine, however I'm curious if there is a way to make use of the alternate constructor which takes params object[] converterParameters and pass over my own custom parameters from the attribute accordingly.

Likewise, I am not sure how to actually retrieve the parameters inside the JsonConverter class definition or if it's even possible to do this with a JsonConverter attribute.

inside the model, attribute with theoretical params, where `some_parameter_here` is a placeholder for a [constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25859094/3744182):

```
[JsonProperty("components")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ComponentsConverter), some_parameter_here)]
public List<ComponentModel> Components { get; set; }
```

ComponentsConverter custom JsonConverter:

```
public class ComponentsConverter : JsonConverter
{   
    public override bool CanConvert (Type t) => t == typeof(List<ComponentModel>);

    public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ... any way to access params object[] customParameters here?
    }
    public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Would be nice to be able to define some custom conversion behavior for specific model properties by using these extra params.

Comment: `[JsonConverter(typeof(ComponentsConverter), "custom_string_value", someCustomObject)]` won't compile because attribute arguments [must be a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25859094/3744182).  So is your question *How can I pass a non-constant value in [`JsonConverterAttribute.ConverterParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute_ConverterParameters.htm)?*  Or is your question, *How to access `JsonConverterAttribute.ConverterParameters` from within the converter?*

Comment: @dbc I am OK with them being constants, those were just placeholder examples (updated it to be more clear) for showing where I wanted to pass things, and yes I am not sure how to access them from within the converter

Comment: Well Json.NET just calls `Activator.CreateInstance(ConverterType, ConverterParameters)` so the converter parameters are passed into the converter's constructor.  You can remember them there and use them in ReadJson() and WriteJson().  See e.g. [Customising Json.NET serialisation based on compile time type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67862096/3744182) and https://dotnetfiddle.net/CjRRtn

Comment: @dbc awesome if you post this as the answer I'll award it to you, ideally paste your code into the answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.NET basically just calls [`Activator.CreateInstance(ConverterType, ConverterParameters)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) <sup>[1]</sup> so the converter parameters are passed into the converter's constructor.  You can remember them there and use them in `ReadJson()` and `WriteJson()` e.g. like so:

```
public class ComponentsConverter : JsonConverter
{   
    public string CustomString { get; init; }

    public ComponentsConverter(string customString)
    {
        // Remember the converter parameters for use in WriteJson() and ReadJson()
        this.CustomString = customString;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert (Type t) => t == typeof(List<ComponentModel>);

    public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Customize the serialized contents using the CustomString passed in to the constructor
        writer.WriteValue(CustomString);
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For a converter applied to the items of a collection, use [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) with [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterParameters.htm).  E.g.:

```
[JsonProperty("components",
              ItemConverterType = typeof(ComponentConverter), 
              ItemConverterParameters = new object [] { "custom_string_value" })]
```

And then:

```
public class ComponentConverter : JsonConverter
{   
    public string CustomString { get; init; }

    public ComponentConverter(string customString)
    {
        // Remember the converter parameters for use in WriteJson() and ReadJson()
        this.CustomString = customString;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert (Type t) => t == typeof(ComponentModel);

    public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Customize the serialized contents using the CustomString passed in to the constructor
        writer.WriteValue(CustomString);
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CjRRtn) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ROXJ2c).

---

**Footnotes:**

[1]: I'm oversimplifying a little here.  It actually uses code-generation techniques to generate and cache delegates on the fly that do the same thing as `Activator.CreateInstance()` but without the performance penalties of late-bound reflection.  See e.g. [`ExpressionReflectionDelegateFactory.ObjectConstructor<object> CreateParameterizedConstructor(MethodBase method)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/e44ab3348fabcbe9ed6b5053b706a9e10b945ba1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ExpressionReflectionDelegateFactory.cs#L44).